# Node is accidentally calling functions of the same name from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a webapp which runs on Node and uses the Express framework.

In the project, I have two modules, `CreateAccountService.js` and `LoginService.js` in the "service" directory.

For now, each module has only one function in its exports.

In the case of the `CreateAccountService.js` module, its exported function is called `create`, and in the case of the `LoginService.js` module, its exported function is called `login`.

By pure coincidence, both of these modules contain a helper function called `validateCredentials`. Also by pure coincidence, both of these helper functions take in two parameters. But the similarities end there. The `validateCredentials` defined in `CreateAccountService.js` is used for checking password complexity and email formatting, whereas the `ValidateCredentials` defined in `LoginService.js` is used for confirming checking the database to make sure the user does have an account, has supplied their correct password, etc.

Here is where it gets weird. When `create` calls `validateCredentials`, it calls the function defined in its own module, just as I would expect it to. HOWEVER, when `login` calls `validateCredentials`, it somehow calls the function defined in `CreateAccountService.js` instead of calling the method definied in its own file, `LoginService.js`.

What's the deal here? In both modules, thier respective `validateCredentails` function is NOT exported. Also, neither of the offending modules (`LoginService.js` and `CreateAccountService.js`) "require" the other.

Shouldn't it be totally impossible for one module to call a method defined in another module, unless that method is exported?

What am I doing wrong? It seems silly to make sure every single function name in my entire project has a unique name.

Below is my code, with irrelevant parts removed or commented out.

LoginService.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('app:LoginService');
var moment = require('moment');
const adminDAO = require('../data_access/AdminDAO.js');
const authDAO = require('../data_access/AuthDAO.js');
const authModel = require('../models/AuthModel.js');

login = function(json, next) {
    validateCredentials(json, function(adminID, err) {
        if (err) {
            next(null, err);
        } else {
            deleteExistingAuth(adminID, function() {
                createSession(adminID, function(token) {
                    next(token, null);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

//This method is never called for some reason...
validateCredentials = function(credentials, next) {
/*
Validates credentials against data stored in the database...
*/
}

exports.login = login;
```

CreateAccountService.js

```
const adminDAO = require('../data_access/AdminDAO.js');
const adminModel = require('../models/AdminModel.js');
const authDAO = require('../data_access/AuthDAO.js');

create = function(json, next) {
    admin = new adminModel(json["firstName"], json["lastName"], json["password"], json["email"]);
    validAdmin(admin, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            checkDuplicates(admin, function(err2) {
                if (err2) {
                    next(err2);
                } else {
                    addAdmin(admin, next);
                }
            })
        }
    });
}

validAdmin = function(admin, next) {
    if (admin._firstName &&
        admin._lastName &&
        admin._passwordHash &&
        admin._email) {
            validateCredentials(admin, next);
    } else {
        err = new Error("Missing one or fields! First name, last name, password, and email are all required!")
        next(err);
    }
}

//This function is called by the "create" method in this module (as it should)
//AND is called by the "login" function in the other module (which it should not)
validateCredentials = function(admin, next) {
    /*
    makes sure that password meets complexity requirements
and that the email is a valid email format

*/
}

exports.create = create;
```

admin.js (This is the file that calls either `create` or `login` depending on the specific route)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const loginService = require('../service/LoginService.js');
const createAccountService = require('../service/CreateAccountService.js');

router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  createAccountService.create(req.body, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(responseFromError(err));
    } else {
      obj = {
        "status":"success"
      }
      res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Hitting the login route");
  loginService.login(req.body, function(authToken, err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(responseFromError(err));
    } else {
      obj = {
        "status":"success",
        "authToken":authToken
      };
      res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Never, ever use a variable in Javascript without declaring it.  If you run in strict mode or run TypeScript, the interpreter/compiler will stop you from doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> login = function(json, next) {
> ```

You assign your functions to variables which you never declare, which makes them implicit globals (and you overwrite the existing ones when you assign a new value to a global of the same name).

Declare them with `const` (or `let` or `var`) so they are scoped to the module.

Start each module with [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to forbid implicit globals and other old JS features that are considered to be risky.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.

I'll avoid not declaring variables in the future. That "use strict" thing sounds like a good idea too.

Comment: To be more precise, **declaring** variables without a `var`, `let` or `const` keyword (it is considered a declaration, not undeclared) creates a global variable